# Where did the snow in Hogsmeade come from?

Tags: harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

In Harry Potter and the Death Hallows (Part 2), when Harry, Hermione and Ron set off to Hogsmeade to find Aberforth - how can it be that there is snow clearly visible through the village but there is no snow visible at Hogwarts, despite them being within walking distance of each other?

Comment: Pretty sure the journey to Hogsmeade from Hogwarts is actually a lot farther written in the book than is portrayed in the movies. [citation needed] of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [**Harry Potter** Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogsmeade#Behind_the_scenes):

> According to [the book] *[Harry Potter Film Wizardry](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Film_Wizardry)*, **the set designers made the decision that Hogsmeade is *"permanently above the [snow line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_line)"***.

[Here](http://members.madasafish.com/~cj_whitehound/Fanfic/map_of_Hogwarts/introduction.htm) you can find a map of *Hogwarts / Hogsmeade*.

[image: Hogwarts]

This is a 'cleaned up' version of [a quick sketch](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/atlas/hogwarts/atlas-h-jkrmap.html) JK Rowling did herself.